# Generate counter with update SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this T-SQL code:

```
DECLARE @DtsAcumGPSData VARCHAR (50);
SET @DtsAcumGPSData='To'+ @NAutobus + 'DtsAcumGPSData'
--
DECLARE @SQL_DtsAcumGPSData NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL_DtsAcumGPSData = N'SELECT 
      COUNTER = 0
      ,[iID]
      ,[iVehicleID]
      ,[fTripDistance]
      ,[dtDateTime]
      ,[fLongitude]
      ,[fLatitude]
      ,[bLatLongValid]
      ,[fSpeed]
      ,[bIgnition]
      ,[bStopFlag]
      ,[fTripTime]
      ,[bWorkHours]
      ,[iLogReason]
      ,[bLatLongValidGuess]
      ,[bAux1]
      ,[bAux2]
      ,[bAux3]
      ,[bAux4]
      ,[bAux5]
      ,[bAux6]
      ,[bAux7]
      ,[bAux8]
INTO '+ @DtsAcumGPSData +
N' FROM GPSData 
WHERE iVehicleID ='+ @NAutobus + --245
N'ORDER BY dtDateTime';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL_DtsAcumGPSData;

-- ##########################################################
-- ACTUALIZANDO CONTADOR
DECLARE @COUNTER INT
SET @COUNTER = 0
DECLARE @SQL_UPDATE_DtsAcumGPSData NVARCHAR (MAX)
SET @SQL_UPDATE_DtsAcumGPSData=
N'UPDATE ' +@DtsAcumGPSData+ N'
SET '+ @COUNTER +N'= COUNTER = ' +@COUNTER+1
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL_UPDATE_DtsAcumGPSData
```

I get this error:

> *Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AutobusGenerico, Line 46
>
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'UPDATE
>   To245DtsAcumGPSData SET ' to data type int*

Any ideas?

I want to set a counter for column `COUNTER`

Answer (score 1):

When you are using [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), your query is a string so when you concatenate a numeric value to it, you must `convert` it or you will get the error.

Your `@Counter` values are `int` and they need to be converted to be included in your query string:

```
DECLARE @COUNTER INT
SET @COUNTER = 0
DECLARE @SQL_UPDATE_DtsAcumGPSData NVARCHAR (MAX)
SET @SQL_UPDATE_DtsAcumGPSData=
N'UPDATE ' +@DtsAcumGPSData+ N'SET '+ cast(@COUNTER as varchar(50)) +N'= COUNTER = ' +cast(@COUNTER+1 as varchar(50))
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL_UPDATE_DtsAcumGPSData
```

Same with this line - it appears that `@NAutobus` is an `int`:

```
WHERE iVehicleID ='+ convert(@NAutobus as varchar(50))
```

These fields must be converted to a string to be concatenated to your query string.

Comment: @lordxeus any values that you are attempting to add to your query string need to be a string datatype.  If it is numeric then you will get the error.

Comment: the counter have 0 in all the rows whats up

Comment: What does the query say if you print the statement?

Comment: count field populates with 0 in all its lines and the object is to fill you as numbered 1,2,3,4 ...

I have no idea how this corregie

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate number with text unless you convert the number to text

```
SET @DtsAcumGPSData='To'+ CAST(@NAutobus AS VARCHAR) + 'DtsAcumGPSData'
```

And

```
INTO '+ CAST(@DtsAcumGPSData AS VARCHAR) +
```

And

```
WHERE iVehicleID ='+ CAST(@NAutobus AS VARCHAR) +
```